# How do I convert the query I use join in Nhibernate to my model?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

```
   var query = Session.QueryOver(() => districtalias).Left.JoinAlias(x => x.DfSystemCityId, () => cityalias).Where(y => y.DistrictName == name)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<GetDfSystemCityDistrict>()).
            Select(y => y.DistrictName)
            .Future<GetDfSystemCityDistrict>();


        IList<GetDfSystemCityDistrict> model = query.ToList();
        return model;
```

I get an error when I want to list the query and cast it in the model.

[image: Screenshot of the actual error]

Ceyhan is my data, GetDfSystemCityDistrict model i want to cast

Comment: Typically, you don't. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities. If you have to use a JOIN like that, it means there are missing relations between the entities. ORMs exist to give the impression of working with in-memory Objects instead of Relational tables. That's what Object-Relational Mapping means.

Comment: BTW that error tells you you tried to use the wrong type. It says nothing about JOINs. Since you posted an image instead of the actual error it's impossible to say *where* that error came from. Post the actual full error text. You can easily get it with `Exception.ToString()` or clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup. The call stack in the exception text shows which method actually threw and which chain of calls led to it.

Comment: The error says that the *string* `Ceyhan` isn't a `GetDfSystemCityDistrict` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select must be before the transformer. Also took the guess that the alias should be in the Select als well.

```
var model = Session.QueryOver<District>()
    .Where(x => x.DistrictName == name)
    .Left.JoinAlias((x => x.DfSystemCityId, () => cityalias)
    .SelectList(l => l
        .Select(x => x.DistrictName)
        .Select(() => cityalias.Name)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<GetDfSystemCityDistrict>())
    .List<GetDfSystemCityDistrict>();
```